# Using std::vector does not work

Tags: c++, stl, containers, clion

Why the following code doesn't compile,

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
vector<int> v; // Error: too few template arguments, expected 2
```

but the same code with `map` (and `pair`, `set`, ...) instead of `vector` works?

```
#include <map>
using std::map;
map<int, int> m; // OK
```

And also this code works fine:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> v; // OK
```

I know that constructor of `std::vector` has two arguments (type and allocator), but why `vector` behaviour is so different from other containers?

UPD: I'm sorry, this is my mistake. Actually the code does compile, but CLion marks it as an error. So it is CLion's bug.
[image]

Comment: [It does compile](https://godbolt.org/g/NdaKMg)

Comment: What compiler are you using? Your code works fine for me

Comment: Don't confuse constructor with template arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is yet not fixed CLion bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5758#u=1454575544687.

As a workaround you can try to use libstdc++ instead of libc++, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5758#comment=27-2389700.